# Problems installing build-essential in RASPBERRY PI 1 MODEL B+

Tags: software-installation, apt

I tried to install the package build-essential under 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential –y
```

but that is the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –y
```

Comment: Why are your trying to install it? The compilers etc should be included in Raspbian.

Comment: I am following a tutorial... "Ensure that you have your build essentials in order: pi@raspberry:~/$ sudo apt-get install build-essential –y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> E: Unable to locate package –y

Probably by now you have realized you should have used:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
```

Note **it does not have to be hit and miss with these things.**  They come with instructions called "man(ual) pages" that are installed along with them.  These are the primary and official references for most commands.  Let's have a look at part of the man page for `apt-get`; you can see it with `man apt-get` (man itself has a man page, see `man man`).

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> apt-get [options] [-o config=string] [-c=cfgfile] command [pkg]

I think this is not too hard to decipher.  Now here's the equivalent of what you did:

```
apt-get command [pkg] [options]
```

But that's not how it works, so it assumes the [options] you passed are a [pkg].